# Given a matrix, find image of the given vector

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a matrix:

$
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
5 & -3 \\
\end {bmatrix}
$

Now, it is asked to find the image of the vector 1, 1 under T.

[image]

So it appears this problem is equivalent to:

$
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
5 & -3 \\
\end {bmatrix}
$ **x** = $
\begin {bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$

If x and y are the solutions, then:

2x + y = 1

5x -3y = 1

or x = 8/11, y = 3/11.

The solutions as per the tutorial should be {3,2}.

Help appreciated how to approach this problem, where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are calculating the preimage of $\binom11$. The image is just $T\binom11=A\cdot\binom11$, so you just have to compute the matrix-vector product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of $(1,1)$ under $T$ is$$T.(1,1)=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\5&-3\end{bmatrix}.(1,1)=(3,2).$$